# node-webkit tail a file output in application console

Tags: node.js, node-webkit

Pardon me if I am totally wrong in some concepts but I am a novice to all of it - node js, node-webkit, javascript. I am trying to learn all of them together :)

I am developing a simple desktop app using node-webkit where I want to read the system log and write it in the application console. I am using tailfd node module and there is no error in the console. here is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Tailing system log</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            var tail = require('tailfd').tail,
            watcher = tail('/var/log/system.log',function(line,tailInfo) {
                //default line listener. optional.
                console.log('line of data> ',line);
            });
        </script>
        <h1>Tailing sys log!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

The tail output is not showing up in the app console. Can you point me if am missing any basic stuff? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `tailfd`, but it doesn't seem to work the way I would expect, by analogy to the shell command `tail -f`.  First it doesn't print anything until the file changes.  Also, it duplicates the tail of the file again, i.e. call it once on a 50 line file, it will print the last 30 lines, add one line to the end it will print the last 30 lines again, including 29 that it already printed.  Try it with some other file that you can modify and see what I mean.  Is that the behavior you're looking for?

Comment: /var/log/system.log is a constantly changing file with new rows added to it quite frequently. I tried it with watching a file of my own that I modified externally and that didn't work either. When I copied the content in between the script element and executed it as a node application (node sample.js), it worked.

Comment: Hmm, modifying my own file worked for me, I think, but I do see the difference in behavior between node and node-webkit when watching system.log.  It looks like watchfd is behaving differently in node-webkit than it does in the node shell.